# With openpyxl, nested list starts writing / appending to cell A2 not A1

Tags: python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I have an excel spreadsheet to calculate data that is added every week for comparison on the first sheet and each additional sheet is the raw data listed as W01 to W52 for each week. I've stripped down the code here to make the issue the only thing not working. In reality, I'm taking multiple CSVs and dumping them into a list, formatting the list and then I am *trying* to write that list into the first unused worksheet.

It is successfully finding the first empty worksheet, but then when it writes the data from the list into it, it is starting at A2 not A1.

So the worksheet already exists. I have tried deleting all the cells and clearing the contents within excel first, but it always starts at A2 not A1.  What am I missing?

*Note: If this helps, originally, I had just deleted last year's data from the worksheet, and when I left it like this, it would start adding the list's data on the first row after the deleted info, such as A52 or something. Deleting the contents of the sheet has "fixed" that issue so it is now only starting at A2 but I want to start it at A1.*

If I manually add something to the A1 cell, it works, such as:

```
ws_week.cell(row=1, column=1).value = 'This should be A1'
```

So I think I can force it to write with a loop for the row number in a loop for the column number, but it seems like the below should be working.

```
import openpyxl

output_excel = 'KB Videos 2021.xlsx' #Excel Report

#opens excel report
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(output_excel) 

#find the first blank worksheet
for sheet in wb.sheetnames:
    if sheet == 'Weekly Stats': 
        pass #ignore first worksheet i.e. calculations
    elif wb[sheet]['A1'].value == None:
        ws_week = wb[sheet]
        break

test=[[1,2,3],['A','B','C'],[4,5,6],['a','b','c']]

for x in test:
    ws_week.append(x)

wb.save(output_excel)

print('Populated ',ws_week.value)`enter code here`)
```

The 1,2,3 from the "test" list are being put into A2, B2, C2 when I expect them to be in A1, B1, C1.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worksheets should never really be considered as "blank". When appending to worksheets, openpyxl uses an internal counter that will start at the **next** below any existing cells. As openpyxl creates cells on demand, `wb[sheet]['A1'].value` will implicitly create the cell "A1" so that it can check the value. This is why data is subsequently appended from the second row. You can avoid this by deleting the row after the check, but you might also want to make the check a little more robust.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. I did end up writing the cell number based loops to get it to go in the right cells.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I used to make it work:

I replaced:

```
for x in test:
    ws_week.append(x)
```

with:

```
# calculate max rows and columns
maxr = len(test)
maxc = len(test[0]) #I could probably put this into the loop in case a column is different, but not with my data

for this_row in range (1, maxr + 1):
    for this_column in range (1, maxc + 1):
        cellsource = test[this_row-1][this_column-1]
        
        ws_week.cell(row = this_row, column = this_column).value = cellsource
```

Comment: This is really difficult to read; you should provide more context but you should probably also use `enumerate()` instead of range. If you really want a **blank** worksheet simply delete and replace.